# Read-only filesystem

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I've resized a partition (ext4) from a Live CD with GParted, and after reboot it says that the file system is read-only.

I've rebooted again from the CD and checked it with GParted with no errors.
How could I find out why does it re-mount the file system in read-only mode?

**edit:** It starts normally, but after some time, the "/" mount point gets remounted with read only settings, so I think it does have errors eventually.
Is there any other way to repair it?

`fstab`:

```
proc                                        /proc   proc   nodev,noexec,nosuid   0   0
UUID=20e01341-4171-43da-99e5-7b49d83d21d5   /       ext4   errors=remount-ro     0   1
UUID=8059f2f1-2cae-44a6-a21d-fe466813e641   none    swap   sw                    0   0
```

`smartctl -a /dev/sda`:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MK3276GSX
Serial Number:    617AP1JTT
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 352601a90
Firmware Version: GS001C
User Capacity:    320.072.933.376 bytes [320 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  Exact ATA specification draft version not indicated
Local Time is:    Wed Oct  3 12:57:01 2012 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x02) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x51) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  84) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003f) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0027   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   100   100   002    Pre-fail  Always       -       1131
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2117
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0025   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       1013
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   142   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1834
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
185 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       65535
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   064   049   040    Old_age   Always       -       36 (Min/Max 29/37)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       62
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       131074
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       14344
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1013         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         3         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

`demsg`:

```
[11782.181320] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_ext_search_left:1224: inode #5636499: comm flush-8:0: ix (17474) != EXT_FIRST_INDEX (0) (depth 1)!
[11782.181331] Aborting journal on device sda1-8.
[11782.183375] EXT4-fs (sda1): Remounting filesystem read-only
[11782.183396] EXT4-fs error (device sda1) in ext4_da_writepages:2317: IO failure
[11782.183584] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_da_writepages: jbd2_start: 992 pages, ino 5636499; err -30
```

Should I try to remove the file with the inode id. `5636499`?
This is the path of the file:

```
~/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/data_3
```

(Is it possible to check if there are other files like this?)

**edit:** After deleting chrome cache, I haven't experienced this error.

Comment: What did the partition contain? Where was it mounted? Also, did you recently switch it from ext3 to ext4? There are some changes in ext4 that will make it read-only to computers without ext4 support

Comment: It contains the operating system and the data, it was the "/" mount point. It was ext4, it was just resized.

Comment: the UUIDs are the same

Comment: I had a [similar problem](http://askubuntu.com/q/141862/12864) that turned out to be a hardware issue. Can you try some of the troubleshooting steps from my question and then update yours please?

Comment: beside being remounted in read-only, can you use the OS? can you install softwares or do something that write to the disk?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something is wrong with the metadata for the chromium cache file. It might not hurt to delete the cache files, but fsck with the -f flag (force) should fix this issue either way. (clarification per IR: run fsck from the livecd, since it needs to be run on an unmounted partition)

```
$ sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sda1
```

If you need to remount the disk in read/write mode, try this:

```
$ sudo mount -vo remount,rw /
```

**Edit:** This seems to be part of a larger, unresolved issue with Ext4. Other people have experienced the same problem after resizing or copying partitions (and sometimes without doing either).

http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/wayland-devel/2012-September/005225.html

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/982490

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1735975.html

[Google Chrome causing file system to mount as read only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186756/google-chrome-causing-file-system-to-mount-as-read-only)

Comment: fsck should only be run on an unmounted partition - at that point it is neither read-only nor read-write.

Comment: I've deleted the chromium chache, but fsck said /dev/sda1 was clean before and after the delete operation. (That's why I was looking for some other way to check the readability of the files. So I could make sure that there are not other wrong files like this.)

Comment: Did you run fsck with the -f option? At the bottom of the launchpad link, someone with the same problem deleted the chromium cache file and the situation seems to have resolved. This may be part of a larger issue with ext4.

Comment: Yes, I ran it with -f option, and I think GParted passes the -t option to e2fsck when checking, too. However I haven't got this error since I deleted the cache.