# Changing rights doesn't work on ./config/JetBrains directory

Tags: command-line, permissions

I'm uninstalling Pycharm Community Edition, and I was trying to remove config and cache directories for IDE, I have executed the below command in terminal without success:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.2
```

After execute the above command, I got all of the files placed inside the folder with a message rm: cannot erase *'path of the file'*: read only file system.

I checked the rights for the folder, I have correctly wrx rights for User and Group, but for others I have only **r** and **x**, I don't know if this is happening due to this other doesn't have w rights, but I tried adding write rights to others with below command:

```
sudo chmod o+w PycharmCE2020.2
```

Once the command ran, I got the message "chmod: changing rights of 'PycharmCE2020.2': Read Only File System", I checked again with ls -l to see if the changes has been reflected, and seems like nothing has happened.

I checked for the owner of the directories and files, and I am the owner.

Comment: Can you do anything in your /home? The read-only filesystem error is usually the OS going into a failsafe mode (typically a disk problem).

Comment: @BrianTurek yes, actualy I checked this question also [https://askubuntu.com/questions/195730/read-only-filesystem] and the solution provided there helped out to solve my problem. It says the same your commenting,